# How to allow user to pick the image with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am writing my first iOS application (iPhone only) with Swift. The main application view should allow user to choose the image from the photo gallery.

I've found the following sample code of **ViewController.swift**:

```
class ViewController: UIImagePickerController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        var imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: { imageP in

        })
    }


    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!) {
        let selectedImage : UIImage = image
        println(selectedImage)
    }

}
```

and have the following View Controller Scene -

```
View Controller
 - Top Layout Guide
 - Bottom Layout Guide
 - View
   - Image View
First Responder
Exit
```

But when I start the app, just black screen is shown. What I am doing wrong?
Another [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/PhotoPicker/Listings/PhotoPicker_APLViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010196-PhotoPicker_APLViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_6) I've found is in Objective-C, which doesn't help me.

Comment: One problem could be that didSselectRowAtIndePath is a delegate call for UITableViewDelegate.  According to your scene layout and your code there isn't a tableview being used here and your ViewController isn't a UITableViewDelegate.  Maybe start will a blank project that works and add a button and fire your code from the button press.

Comment: @LA_ i don't understand why the tableView functions are involved here?

Comment: It's working and well tested just go to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717115/how-to-uiimagepickercontroller-for-camera-and-photo-library-in-the-same-time-in/49169339#49169339

Comment: please look it this alos, https://theswiftdev.com/picking-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-5/

Answer (score 148, accepted):

If you just want let the user choose image with UIImagePickerController use this code:

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    @IBAction func btnClicked() {

        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Button capture")

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in

        })

        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I don't want user to press the button to choose the image?

Comment: remove the @IBaction from the func and call the func when ever you want let say in the viewDidLoad or anytime you want just call it

Comment: Thanks. It says `Attempt to present <UIImagePickerController: 0x7fdb84029800> on <MyApp.ViewController: 0x7fdb838360a0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`. Should I add something to the Scene?

Comment: I upvoted bc this was really helpful. Just had to change NSDictionary to [NSObject: AnyObject] and works great!

Comment: @DekelMaman there was a suggested edit in the review queue to make it Swift3, but [it was of poor quality](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15680221), so I rejected it and made a proper edit to avoid more suggestions

Comment: how can i get the image from gallery ?

Comment: @PareshHirpara just use the sourceType for example, imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;

Comment: https://theswiftdev.com/picking-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-5/

Answer (score 123):

Complete copy-paste working image picker for **swift 4** based on @user3182143 answer:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


class ImagePickerManager: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    var picker = UIImagePickerController();
    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    var pickImageCallback : ((UIImage) -> ())?;
    
    override init(){
        super.init()
        let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default){
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openCamera()
        }
        let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default){
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openGallery()
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel){
            UIAlertAction in
        }

        // Add the actions
        picker.delegate = self
        alert.addAction(cameraAction)
        alert.addAction(galleryAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    }

    func pickImage(_ viewController: UIViewController, _ callback: @escaping ((UIImage) -> ())) {
        pickImageCallback = callback;
        self.viewController = viewController;

        alert.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.viewController!.view

        viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func openCamera(){
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)){
            picker.sourceType = .camera
            self.viewController!.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alertController: UIAlertController = {
                let controller = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: "You don't have camera", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default)
                controller.addAction(action)
                return controller
            }()
            viewController?.present(alertController, animated: true)
        }
    }
    func openGallery(){
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.viewController!.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    //for swift below 4.2
    //func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    //    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    //    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    //    pickImageCallback?(image)
    //}
    
    // For Swift 4.2+
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        guard let image = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
            fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        }
        pickImageCallback?(image)
    }



    @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, pickedImage: UIImage?) {
    }

}
```

Call it from your viewcontroller like this:

```
    ImagePickerManager().pickImage(self){ image in
        //here is the image
    }
```

Also don't forget to include the following keys in your `info.plist`:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
```

Comment: Had to replace func `imagePickerController` with this to make it work. Thanks!

```func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
        pickImageCallback?(image)
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }```

Comment: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UIAlertController can only have one action with a style of UIAlertActionStyleCancel'
I get this error with the code above.

Comment: I added the following code to fix the issue:

if alert.actions.count > 0 {    // alert called again after canceling
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            alert.addAction(cameraAction)
            alert.addAction(galleryAction)
            alert.addAction(cancelAction)
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

Comment: @Ing.Ron the addActions need to be set only once, hence they should sit in the init method instead - I've updated the code. Let me know if you get any issues with that

Comment: @vir us: Many thanks for your fast response! In my case I put your init() code in the viewDidLoad() which works fine for me!

Comment: Retain cycle problem here: viewController var should be weak

Comment: thanks @EdoardoVicoli - happy if you suggest a tested edit as I'm no longer have an environment to test it on my end.

Comment: If you are developing for iPad use UIAlertController.Style.alert instead of .actionSheet to avoid crash when presenting UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

Answer (score 43):

For Swift 3:

1. First, you need to add the following key in info.plist:

   ```
       <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
   <string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
   ```
2. Your View controller needs to conform to the following protocols:
   `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`, `UINavigationControllerDelegate`:

   ```
   class ImagePickerViewController:  UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {}
   ```
3. You need to declare the UIImage you will be useing to bind the returned/selected image:

   ```
   @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
   @IBoutlet weak var upLoadImageBtn:UIImage!
   let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
   ```
4. Set the pickerImage delegate to be your ViewController:

   ```
   imagePicker.delegate = self
   ```
5. For the upload button, you will need to link to the following image in order to fire the action and display the image picker:

   ```
   @IBAction func upLoadImageBtnPressed(_ sender: AnyObject) {
       imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
       imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary


       /*
       The sourceType property wants a value of the enum named        UIImagePickerControllerSourceType, which gives 3 options:

       UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
       UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
       UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum

       */
       present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }
   ```
6. Your View controller needs to implement the delegate methods for the image picker delegates:

   ```
   // MARK: - ImagePicker Delegate

   func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

       if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
           myImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
           myImageView.image = pickedImage
       }


       /*

       Swift Dictionary named “info”.  
       We have to unpack it from there with a key asking for what media information we want.
       We just want the image, so that is what we ask for.  For reference, the available options are:

       UIImagePickerControllerMediaType
       UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage
       UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage
       UIImagePickerControllerCropRect
       UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL
       UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL
       UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata

       */
       dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
   }

   func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
       dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 15):

In Swift 5 you have to do this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func setPicture(_ sender: Any) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = image
        }

    }




}
```

Answer (score 13):

I will give you best understandable coding for pick the image,refer this

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) 
{
     var alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
     var cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
     {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openCamera()
     }
     var gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallary", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
     {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openGallary()
     }
     var cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
     {
        UIAlertAction in
     }

    // Add the actions
     picker?.delegate = self
     alert.addAction(cameraAction)
     alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
     alert.addAction(cancelAction)
     self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func openCamera()
{
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera))
    {
        picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self .presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    else
    {
        let alertWarning = UIAlertView(title:"Warning", message: "You don't have camera", delegate:nil, cancelButtonTitle:"OK", otherButtonTitles:"")
        alertWarning.show()
    }
}
func openGallary()
{
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//PickerView Delegate Methods
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])
{
    picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageView.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    println("picker cancel.")
}
```

Have a nice day:-)

Answer (score 8):

```
    @IBAction func chooseProfilePicBtnClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openCamera()
    }
    let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallary", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
            self.openGallary()
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel)
        {
            UIAlertAction in
    }

    // Add the actions
    picker.delegate = self
    alert.addAction(cameraAction)
    alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func openCamera(){
    if(UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)){
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera
        self .presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }else{
        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Warning"
        alert.message = "You don't have camera"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
        alert.show()
    }
}
func openGallary(){
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
//MARK:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]){
    picker .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    imageViewRef.image=info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
}
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController){
    print("picker cancel.")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**XCODE 10.1 / SWIFT 4.2 :**

1. Add required permissions (others mentioned)
2. Add this class to your view:

---

```
    import UIKit

    import Photos

    import Foundation

class UploadImageViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            checkPermission()

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }

        @IBAction func btnSetProfileImageClickedCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
        }

        @IBAction func btnSetProfileImageClickedFromGallery(_ sender: UIButton) {
            self.selectPhotoFromGallery()
        }

        func selectPhotoFromGallery() {
            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

            if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                    self.imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                    self.imgView.image = pickedImage
                }

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController){
            print("cancel is clicked")
        }


        func checkPermission() {
            let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
            switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
            case .authorized:
                print("Access is granted by user")
            case .notDetermined:
                PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
                    (newStatus) in
                    print("status is \(newStatus)")
                    if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                        /* do stuff here */
                        print("success")
                    }
                })
                print("It is not determined until now")
            case .restricted:
                // same same
                print("User do not have access to photo album.")
            case .denied:
                // same same
                print("User has denied the permission.")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is question is a year old, but here's some pretty simple code (mostly from [this tutorial](http://www.codingexplorer.com/choosing-images-with-uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift/)) that's working well for me:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imagePicker.delegate = self
}

@IBAction func loadImageButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("hey!")
    self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    self.imagePicker.sourceType = .SavedPhotosAlbum

    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        self.imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        self.imageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    self.imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: A more in depth tutorial than the one I referenced can be found [here](http://makeapppie.com/2014/12/04/swift-swift-using-the-uiimagepickercontroller-for-a-camera-and-photo-library/)

Answer (score 3):

Do this stuff for displaying photo library images swift coding:

```
var pkcrviewUI = UIImagePickerController()
        if UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
        {
            pkcrviewUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            pkcrviewUI.allowsEditing = true
            pkcrviewUI.delegate = self
            [self .presentViewController(pkcrviewUI, animated: true , completion: nil)]
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Of course, above answers solve the main problem.

I faced a crash in Swift 3.0 while launching the photo album because Info.plist did not had these flags:

1. Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description  -> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
2. Privacy - Camera Usage Description -> NSCameraUsageDescription

[[image: screenshot[1]]

Please add them if you face similar issue.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

**For Swift 4**
This code working for me!!

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var chooseBuuton: UIButton!
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
    }
    @IBAction func btnClicked() {

    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum) 
    {
        print("Button capture")
        imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

  @objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    imageView.image = chosenImage

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode 10, Swift 4.2**

Below is a slightly optimized version of the implementation.
This is in Swift 4.2 and I have tested it too.

You can see the complete code for ViewController here.
Please note that you have to define an IBOutlet (imageView) and IBAction (didTapOnChooseImageButton) defined and connected in storyboard too. Hope this helps.

```
import UIKit

class ImagePickViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func didTapOnChooseImageButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert:UIAlertController=UIAlertController(title: "Choose Image", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)
    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openCamera(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera)
    }
    let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallary", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        self.openCamera(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary)
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
    }

    // Add the actions
    imagePicker.delegate = self as UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate
    alert.addAction(cameraAction)
    alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func openCamera(_ sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = sourceType
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK:UIImagePickerControllerDelegate

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                                    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    print("imagePickerController cancel")
}

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Nish! Code-only answers are discouraged here, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand :)

Comment: Much appreciated, @Joel. I have updated the answer per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

You can do like here

```
var avatarImageView = UIImageView()
var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        
func takePhotoFromGallery() {
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    
    present(imagePicker, animated: true)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        avatarImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        avatarImageView.image = pickedImage
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

here is an easy way to do it:

but first you have to add ( Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description ) in the info.plist, and you should have a button and a UIImageView in your viewController.

then create an outlet of the UIImageView ( in this code the outlet is called myImage), and an action of the button ( I called the action importing in my code )

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    @IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
    @IBAction func importing(_ sender: Any) {
        let Picker = UIImagePickerController()
        Picker.delegate = self
        Picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        self.present(Picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        Picker.allowsEditing = true
        Picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
    }

     func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
    {
        let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage //1
        myImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit //2
        myImage.image = chosenImage //3
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) //4
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBAction func ImportImage(_ sender: Any)
{
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary

    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {
        //After it is complete
    }


}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage
    {
        myimage.image = image
    }
    else{
        //
    }
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

Add `UINavigationControllerDelegate`, `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` delegates in the class definition

Comment: Add comments, explain your answer, read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Incase if you don't want to have a separate button, here is a another way. Attached a gesture on imageView itself, where on tap of image a alert will popup with two option. You will have the option to choose either from gallery/photo library or to cancel the alert.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddDetailsViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

var picker:UIImagePickerController? = UIImagePickerController()

@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let managedContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as? AppDelegate)!.managedObjectContext

    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Person", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    let person = Person(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    person.image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image!, 1.0) //imageView.image

    do {
         try person.managedObjectContext?.save()
         //people.append(person)
       } catch let error as NSError {
         print("Could not save \(error)")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(AddDetailsViewController.tapGesture(_:)))
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

    picker?.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tapGesture(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Profile Picture Options", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let gallaryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Gallary", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in self.openGallary()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in self.cancel()
    }

    alert.addAction(gallaryAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}


func openGallary() {
    picker!.allowsEditing = false
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    presentViewController(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageView.image = pickedImage
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func cancel(){
    print("Cancel Clicked")
}

}
```

Adding more to the question, implemented the logic to store images in CoreData.

Answer (score 0):

click on button and open Image gallery and set image in imageview swift 3.0

add three delegate
UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UIPopoverControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
var picker:UIImagePickerController?=UIImagePickerController()
@IBOutlet var imgPhoto: UIImageView!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker?.delegate=self
   }

 @IBAction func btnAddPhotoClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
    openGallary()
   }

func openGallary()
{
    picker!.allowsEditing = false
    picker!.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    present(picker!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//MARK:- ImagePicker Controller Delegate
//MARK:-

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: 
UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        imgPhoto.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        imgPhoto.image = chosenImage
    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it's easy.. to Pic a Image using **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate**

```
    @objc func masterAction(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.savedPhotosAlbum){
            print("Button capture")

            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .savedPhotosAlbum;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        print("hello i'm touch \(sender.tag)")
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker:
        UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            print("Get Image \(chosenImage)")
            ImageList.insert(chosenImage, at: 0)
            ArrayList.insert("", at: 0)
            Collection_Vw.reloadData()
        } else{
            print("Something went wrong")
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pick only normal image you can use below code,that check that the picked image is not panorama image.

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()

func photoFromLibrary() {

        self.picker.allowsEditing = true
        self.picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        //picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!

        self.present(self.picker, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

func shootPhoto() {

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera) {
                self.picker.allowsEditing = true
                self.picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
                self.picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
                self.picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                self.present(self.picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
            }

}

//Image picker delegate
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let str = "\(info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"]!)"

    let s = str.slice(from: "{", to: "}")

    if let arr = s?.components(separatedBy: ","){
        if arr.count >= 2 {
            if Int(arr[0])! > 11000 {
                picker.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
                self.makeToast("Invalid Image!!!")
                return
            }
                     }
        }
    }

    if  let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage{
        self.UserImageView.image = image
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController)
{
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For Swift 3.4.1, this code is working:

```
implements                                                             
class AddAdvertisementViewController : UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate  

var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()                                
var file :UIImage!

 //action sheet tap on image

 func tapOnButton(){   
    let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Add Photo", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    let galleryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Gallery", style: .default, handler:{
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.addImageOnTapped()
    })

    let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: .default, handler:{
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        self.openCameraButton()
    })

    let cancleAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler:{
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancel")
    })

    optionMenu.addAction(galleryAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(cameraAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(cancleAction)
    self.present(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func openCameraButton(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)
    {
        imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


func addImageOnTapped(){
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary){
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

//picker pick image and store value imageview
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]){
    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    {
            file = image
            imgViewOne.image = image
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);
    }
}
```