# How to pickup multiple images from photo gallery in iOS 8 Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building an app for iOS 8 using `Swift` and I need to allow the user select more than one image from the photo gallery. But all code examples using `UIImagePickerController` works with just one photo at a time like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510081/how-to-allow-user-to-pick-the-image-with-swift)

Is there any way to select more than one photo at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UIImagePickerController` no. You could write your custom picker or use something ready, like [CTAssetsPickerController](https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController)