# Swift UI camera shows portrait view but image turns out landscape

Tags: ios, swift, camera, swiftui

I'm trying to get camera preview and photos working in a swiftUI app, I can display the preview and snap a photo but proportions are coming out wrong. The preview screen looks good, but as soon as the capture happens, it gets distorted and doesn't stay in portrait.

The preview screen looks like this:

[image]

Some code:

```
class CameraController: UIViewController {
    //...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        //...
        // Setup preview layer
        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        previewLayer?.frame = view.frame
        view.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer!, at: 0)
        //...
    }
}
```

But after I snap a photo, the `Image` I'm displaying in a `VStack` looks like:

[image]

The code is:

```
VStack {
    Image(uiImage: self.inputImage!)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

I'm using `.fit` because I want to see the whole thing, and it's just coming out all wrong. Also, here's my camera setup code happening inside `viewDidLoad`:

```
captureSession.beginConfiguration()

// Get device
captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: .video, position: .back)

do {
    // Create input
    let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice!)
    captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

    // Create output
    photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
    photoOutput?.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray(
        [AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])],
        completionHandler: nil
    )
    captureSession.connections.first?.videoOrientation = .portrait // tested with and and without this line
    captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns only on landscape because the image which was taken with in-app camera has an orientation. You need to normalize it and display it.

I make an extension of UIImage with

```
func fixOrientation(img:UIImage) -> UIImage {

  if (img.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientation.Up) { 
      return img;
  }

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(img.size, false, img.scale);
  let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: img.size.width, height: img.size.height)
  img.drawInRect(rect)

  let normalizedImage : UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return normalizedImage;

}
```

Original answer from here:
[Normalize Pictures taken by camera](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27775741/12035498)

Also I just did a few changes to copy and paste solution for the ImagePickerManager:

[ImagePickerManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172065/12035498)