# How do you display an image in a UIImageView that was selected using UIImagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm very new to Xcode and Swift, and I was trying to display an image in a `UIImageView` that was selected using `UIImagePickerController`. I linked the `UIImageView` using an `@IBOutlet` and I put some `if` statements at the bottom to allow for editing of the selected picture, but I got stuck when an error popped up in my code. I'm pretty sure that the problem has something to do with how I am referencing the `UIImageView`, but I don't know how to do it in a different way. I just got this account to ask this question, so forgive me for the way I made this post.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func openPhotosButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        showImagePickerController()
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var characterView: UIImageView!

}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func showImagePickerController() {
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(imagePickerController, animated: true)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as UIImage {
            characterView.image = editedImage
        }
        else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as UIImage {
            characterView.image = originalImage
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Picture from Xcode:

[image: picture from Xcode]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow user to pick the image with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510081/how-to-allow-user-to-pick-the-image-with-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your method to this one

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let editedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            characterView.image = editedImage
        }
        else if let originalImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            characterView.image = originalImage
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked like a charm! So the change was that I have to use the '.InfoKey' and us 'as?' instead of 'as'?

Comment: I'm also trying to make this app upload multiple photos and organize them in a kind of album. Any quick tips or specific classes I could use?