# How do I go to the next screen after pressing "Use Photo" in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, storyboard

I am currently creating a simple app in Swift for an iPhone. When the I press the button "Take Photo" the camera opens up, so I can take a picture. Then when I press "Use Photo", it just stays on the first screen with the "Take Photo" button. How do I get the app to show the next screen/storyboard after pressing "Use Photo"?

Comment: You need to dismiss the image picker

Answer (score 0):

On your home screen there are two buttons...

```
1. Take Photo
2. Use Photo
```

So when you click on Take photo, it opens camera & you're able to capture photo alright.

Now when you're on home screen, when you press `Use Photo` button, it doesn't go to image library right.

So from this, scenario onwards, I'll provide you solution to use photo.

**Solution :** Please go through this, here I'm using image-picker on button click. It will allow you to select/choose image and assign your selected image to a `UIImageView`.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    @IBAction func btnUsePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        if UIImagePickerController .isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary)
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            self .present(imagePicker, animated: true , completion: nil)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let pickerImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            self.imageView.image = pickerImage
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }

    }
}
```

I hope, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your answer is here:

[ImagePickerManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51172065/12035498)

It's a copy&paste solution for taking images. I just did a few little changes.

Don't forget to set the right orientation of the picture when taking landscape picture:

[Normalize Pictures taken by camera](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27775741/12035498)